# How to use a variable used as a column tracker in a formula

Tags: excel, vba

In a code using a loop, I use a variable as a column tracker. When some conditions are met, I want to insert a formula in a specific cell, using this variable as the column of one of the cell mentioned in the formula. 
I created a very similar code, but the variable "m" was a row tracker instead of a column tracker and I was successfully using the following line:

`If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then Cells(n, 4).Formula = "=AM4-sum(D10:D" & m & ")"`

I want to use this m as a column and not as a row, here is a unsuccessful attempt:

`If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then Cells(11, n).Formula = "=AM4-SUM(Range(Cells(11, 7), Cells(11, " & m & ")))"`

Can someone help me about the synthax of the 2d line in order to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use `RANGE ` and `CELLS ` in a worksheet function. You can, however, use `ADDRESS ` instead. First argument is the row number, second argument the column number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Address for Excel Formula

The 1st sub serves as a quick solution to the problem. It can be successfully run if values are assigned to `m` and `n`. You can run the 2nd and 3rd subs as they are.

```
Option Explicit

' A Quick Solution
Sub Quick()
    Dim m As Long, n As Long
    If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then
        Cells(11, n).Formula = "=AM4-SUM(" _
          & Range(Cells(11, 7), Cells(11, m)).Address(0, 0) _
          & ")"
    End If
End Sub

' The Versions
Sub Results()
    Const EF1 As String = "=AM4-SUM("
    Const EF3 As String = ")"

    Dim m As Long, n As Long, EF2 As String
    n = 1

    m = 10 ' At least 10 (Note the different results for 10).

    'If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then Cells(n, 4).Formula = _
      "=AM4-SUM(D10:D" & m & ")"

    ' Old String Version (You can replace "D" with 4.)
    If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then
        EF2 = "D10:D" & m
        Cells(n, "D").Formula = EF1 & EF2 & EF3
    End If
Debug.Print "D10:D" & m
    ' Old Range Version (You can replace "D" with 4.)
    If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then
        EF2 = Range(Cells(10, "D"), Cells(m, "D")).Address(0, 0)
        Cells(n, "D").Formula = EF1 & EF2 & EF3
    End If
Debug.Print Range(Cells(10, "D"), Cells(m, "D")).Address(0, 0)
    'If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then Cells(11, n).Formula = _
      "=AM4-SUM(Range(Cells(11, 7), Cells(11, " & m & ")))"

    m = 7 ' At least 7.

    ' New Range Version (You can replace "G" with 7.)
    If Cells(8, n).Value = "F" Then
        EF2 = Range(Cells(11, "G"), Cells(11, m)).Address(0, 0)
        Cells(11, n).Formula = EF1 & EF2 & EF3
    End If
Debug.Print Range(Cells(11, "G"), Cells(11, m)).Address(0, 0)

End Sub


' A Possible Scenario (Old Range Version)
Sub monitorOldRange()

    Const sumFR As Long = 10        ' Sum First Row Number
    Const sumLRStart As Long = 11   ' Sum Starting Last Row Number
    Const sumCol As Long = 4        ' Sum Column Number

    Const srcFC As Long = 1         ' Source First Column Number
    Const srcLC As Long = 5         ' Source Last Column Number
    Const srcRow As Variant = 8     ' Source Criteria Row Number
    Const Criteria As String = "F"  ' Source Criteria String

    Const tgtCol As Long = 4        ' Target Column Number

    Dim scc As Long                 ' Source Column Counter
    Dim sumLR As Long               ' Sum Last Row Counter
    Dim EF As String                ' Excel Formula

    Debug.Print String(50, "-") & vbCr & "Old Range Version:"

    sumLR = sumLRStart
    For scc = srcFC To srcLC
'        EF = "=AM64-SUM(D10:D" _
'          & fcc _
'          & ")"
        EF = "=AM64-SUM(" _
          & Range(Cells(sumFR, sumCol), Cells(sumLR, sumCol)).Address(0, 0) _
          & ")"
        Debug.Print Cells(srcRow, scc).Address, Cells(scc, tgtCol).Address, EF
'        If Cells(srcRow, scc).Value = Criteria Then
'             Cells(scc, tgtCol).Formula = EF
'        End If
        sumLR = sumLR + 1
    Next scc

End Sub
```